# thタグを縦に表示するhtmlテーブルを、マークダウン経由で表示できる？ そもそもhtml的に正しい？

Tags: html, markdown

**Q1.下記リンク先で「1列目を見出しに指定したテーブル例」が掲載されていますが、マークダウンでこういったhtml(thタグを縦に並べたテーブル)を表示することは出来るでしょうか？**
・マークダウン拡張としての例はない？

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>見出し1</th>
<td>データ1-1</td>
<td>データ1-2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>見出し2</th>
<td>データ2-1</td>
<td>データ2-2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>見出し3</th>
<td>データ3-1</td>
<td>データ3-2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[Link](http://www.tagindex.com/html5/table/table.html)

---

**Q2.これまで全く気にしていなかったのですが、thタグが縦に並んでいるテーブルはそもそもHTMLとして正しいのでしょうか？**
・theadとtbodyに分離出来ないと思うのですが……
・別に分離しなくても良い？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1. マークダウンではサポートしていないと思います。そのままHTMLで書くしかないでしょうね。

A2. 以下のHTMLを[Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/check)で検証してみましたが、特にエラーは出ませんでした。FireFoxでも正常に表示されます。なので、おそらく問題はないと思います。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>見出し1</th>
<td>データ1-1</td>
<td>データ1-2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>見出し2</th>
<td>データ2-1</td>
<td>データ2-2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>見出し3</th>
<td>データ3-1</td>
<td>データ3-2</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

詳細は[W3Cの最新のHTML仕様](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/tabular-data.html#the-th-element)を参照してみて下さい。

Answer (score 1):

`<th>`要素には`scope`という任意で指定できる属性が定義されており、ヘッダーの対象範囲を指定することができます。この属性の取りうる値は以下の通りです。

- `col`
- `colgroup`
- `row`
- `rowgroup`
- `auto` (既定値)

ですので1個または複数の`<tr>`に対してヘッダーに対して`<th>`を配置するのは仕様で想定されている記述です。

さらに言えば`<td>`側の`headers`属性で対応する`<th>`を指定することも可能ですので、`<th>`は`<table>`内のどこにあってもセマンティクス上の問題はありません。